# Create a new Column in pandas dataframe based on the filetered values in the row of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe which has the following columns:

|  | Date | Zip | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-01 | 90102 | 58.02 |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 | 90102 | 81.55 |
| 2 | 2019-01-01 | 90102 | 11.97 |
| 3 | 2019-01-01 | 90102 | 93.23 |
| 4 | 2019-01-01 | 90103 | 13.68 |

I want to create a 4th column which should have ratio of price based on the max price in that zip and on that date.

So I have used another df called df_max_price

```py
df_max_price = df.groupby(['Date','Zip'], as_index=False)['Price'].max()
```

|  | Date | Zip | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-01 | 90102 | 93.23 |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 | 90103 | 13.68 |

Now I want to have a new column in the df which shall be the ratio of Price and maxprice for that date and zip code

|  | Date | Zip | Price | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-01 | 90102 | 58.02 | 0.622 |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 | 90102 | 81.55 | 0.875 |
| 2 | 2019-01-01 | 90102 | 11.97 | 0.128 |
| 3 | 2019-01-01 | 90102 | 93.23 | 1.000 |
| 4 | 2019-01-01 | 90103 | 13.68 | 1.000 |

The calculation is based on `58.02/93.23` and so on.

Can someone help me showing how it can be done using lambda function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `transform`

```
df['ratio'] = df['Price'] / df.groupby(['Date','Zip'], as_index=False)['Price'].transform('max')['Price']

         Date    Zip  Price     ratio
0  2019-01-01  90102  58.02  0.622332
1  2019-01-01  90102  81.55  0.874718
2  2019-01-01  90102  11.97  0.128392
3  2019-01-01  90102  93.23  1.000000
4  2019-01-01  90103  13.68  1.000000
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use as string to np.max, Isnt that max slowing down the system?

Comment: Hi, @It_is_Chris, this works but gives a warning

```
/opt/conda/condapub/condamt_2020q3/u18/envs/py36ml_2020q3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:


A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

```

Comment: @AkhilGupta that is not an issue with the answer but an issue with how you created the variable `df` You, at some point, created a slice of a larger pandas data frame. You should find that and add `.copy()` to the end. [Setting with  copy warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Thank you so much! :)